# Working with views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, view

in my App I have 3 UIViews (3 .xib) and 3 buttons for every view one button but the problem that I didn't know how to program the views always I have errors and warning I tried to make the view appear like the info button in the utility application but I must make a back to the original view and I faced problem with delegation

**So is there any way to make the view appear by pressing its button** exactly like a TabBareController because **I want the buttons always exists in every view** and I don't want to use an application that uses a tab bar.

Thanks

Edit:

in the firstViewControler.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

//Load the image   
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_tweet_S.png"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *tweet = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tweet setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//sets the frame of the button to the size of the image
tweet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

//creates a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
UIBarButtonItem *tweetbar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tweet];

tweetbar.tag = 1;

//Load the image   
UIImage *pageImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_web.png"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *page = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[page setImage:pageImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[page addTarget:self action:@selector(flipAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//sets the frame of the button to the size of the image
page.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pageImage.size.width, pageImage.size.height);

//creates a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
UIBarButtonItem *pagebar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:page];

pagebar.tag = 2;

//Load the image   
UIImage *infoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_info.png"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[infoButton setImage:infoImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//sets the frame of the button to the size of the image
infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, infoImage.size.width, infoImage.size.height);

//creates a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
UIBarButtonItem *infoBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
//infoBar.target= self;
//infoBar.action= @selector(showInfo:);
//infoBar.tag = 3;
UIBarItem* space = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
                     UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil  action:nil] autorelease];

_toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:
            CGRectMake(0, 460 - 44, 320, 44)];
_toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
_toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,tweetbar, space,pagebar,space,infoBar,space, nil];


[self.view addSubview:_toolbar];

[tweetbar release];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and in every view the same code

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make a view appear by pressing a button. And yes you can make buttons exist is every view by adding them to every view. Post your code. Show us what you have tried doing, then we'll work on solving your problem from there.

Comment: see the edited Question i'm trying to make a toolbar appear in the 3 views but i dont know how to handle  flipAction: and showInfo: according to my code

Comment: You're just creating buttons and a toolbar there. You didn't show what flipAction: and showInfo: does. Add that code, and all others that you think are relevant.

Comment: flipAction: and showInfo: are my problem I tried to make write this: -(void)showinfo:(id)sender{
webViewController *controller; 
controller = [[webViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"web" ...]; ... }
and i wrote delegate all the stuff but this is not good way because of the back button (done method) it will return to the original view where showinfo written

Comment: If those are your problem then provide the code and tell us what they should be doing and what is currently happening.

Comment: as u can notice from my code there are 3 buttons in my App (inside the toolbar), the App run with first button selected (first view) the second button call flipAction to show second view (web page) and the last button call showinfo to show third view (about us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can squeeze out of your posts, you want to be able to move between 3 views in random orders. Using a navigation controller and pushViewController:/popViewController: is not very good for this.

Better use a tab bar.

Comment: my problem was putting a picture inside a tab bar, but recently I solve it. so I will use the tab bar now